# Best Simple method for using reCAPTCHA PHP Plugin in website

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have used google api's and the code below to get captcha on my website but unable to get it on php website.
I have used below code

```
<html><body>
<?
require_once ("recaptchalib.php");
// get a key at http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey
$mailhide_pubkey = '';
$mailhide_privkey = '';
?>
The Mailhide encoding of example@example.com is
<?
echo recaptcha_mailhide_html ($mailhide_pubkey,
                              $mailhide_privkey,
                              "example@example.com");
?>.
<br>
The url for the email is:
<?
echo recaptcha_mailhide_url ($mailhide_pubkey,
                             $mailhide_privkey,
                             "example@example.com");
?>
<br>
</body></html>
```

Please advice me the simple and best steps to get Captcha on Php website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't follow this method it's somewhat tough to manage.

If you just simply want to integrate Google New reCaptcha then just [register here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

And generate a secret key and manage it in your form. You can follow below link for more detail.

[Google reCaptcha Using PHP | Only 2 Step Integration](http://www.allinformer.com/google-recaptcha-using-php/)

Comment: No Need of this. Enjoy